# Is Laravel changing Content-type of my .css files?

Tags: php, css, content-type

Today I tried to publish a site developed in Laravel. When I have send all my files on the server I realised that styles are not being applied.
Css file are being loaded, because I get in console:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xxx.xx/build/css/app-e3022e1832.css"`

And I think here is the problem. Take a look at headers of `app-e3022e1832.css`, escpecialy at `Content-Type`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 14:27:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: IdeaWebServer/v0.80
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

When I put the same .css file on an external server, than the file gets `Content-Type: text/css` and everything is working fine. The same thing happens when I deleted all Laravel files, than my css files are getting normal `Content-Type: text/css` and styles are being applied properly.

That gives us a proposal, that Laravel is changing the `Content-Type` of `.css` files, but I used Laravel in another projects and everything was working fine.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with Laravel, but with the `.htaccess` file. When I uploaded files to the server I realised that I need php7. My hosting provider allows to choose php version in htaccess files. I wrote on the top of my .htaccess:

```
use php7
```

But that was wrong. I should write:

```
:Location /*.php
Use php7
:Location
```

This is maybe very custom solution and very special problem, but if somebody have a similar problem to mine, you can make sure that everything is okay with your php version and `.htaccess` file.